# How to pass data from database to JSF page?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to pass data from database to JSF page as a table. I know that I can use `ArrayList` but I need more efficient way because I have database tables with 2000+ rows and more. I;m not sure but the `ArrayList` will consume too much memory. Is there more memory efficient way to send the data to the JSF page?

P.S maybe using pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with a simple [PrimeFaces - DataTable - Pagination](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf) Example... its really simple and efficient...

> DataTable has built-in support for ajax pagination.

Then if you will deal with really huge data you can take a look at a more advanced example.

Take a look at the [PrimeFaces DataTable - Lazy Loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) example

> DataTable has built-in support to deal with huge datasets. In order to enable lazy loading, a LazyDataModel needs to be implemented to query the datasource when pagination, sorting, filtering or live scrolling happens

And here is a link to all [PrimeFaces Datatable ability's](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf)

Answer (score 2):

With Richfaces you can use database backed pagination. There is a bunch of example/tutorials if you search for richfaces pagination. Here is one that looks promising:

http://www.myjeeva.com/2011/04/do-jsfrichfacesseam-lazydynamic-data-loading-pagination/